Write the launch function "MainActivity.java" code in the source code "MainActivity.kt"
Please, help me write the launch function "MainActivity.java" code in the source code "MainActivity.kt".
"MainActivity.kt" source code:
package com.mycompany.marketplace

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}

Please, help me write the launch function "MainActivity.java" code in the source code "MainActivity.kt".

Why would you want to do that? Where is your problem?

Here's sample code function in JavaActivity.java corresponding to the Kotlin file KotlinActivity.kt, you may need to translate the Kotlin code into Java. Here's a basic sample of code:
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class JavaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_java);

    // Create an intent to open KotlinActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, KotlinActivity.class);
    
    // Start the KotlinActivity
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}

